# How to plot a graph from the data extracted from mysql through python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mysql-connector

```
import mysql.connector as myc
from mysql.connector import Error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

db = myc.connect(host='localhost',database='patients',user='root',password='root')
mc = db.cursor()
mc.execute('select count(*) from corona group by date')
for i in mc:
    x=[]
    x=x.append(i)
mc.execute('select distinct date from corona ')
for j in mc:
    y=[]
    y=y.append(j)
    
plt.plot([x],[y])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

this is the code we are using here for plotting a line graph. what we are expecting is that the graph should show distinct dates in ascending order.
we wanted to plot a graph with the no.of patients that have entered that day versus the date.
we wanted to show a gradual increase or decrease in the count.
but this code does not show that (the image attached) and no error is also shown.
we can't find what is wrong also. please help.
I would really appreciate any answer but with a little minimum explanation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIJ51.png)

Comment: You've to fetch all the results of the query by using `mc.fetchall()` and store it in a variable. And then iterate over that var to get all the rows.

Comment: for both queries is it?? and if iterate do I have to save that data in arrays....please bare with if you feel they are unnecessary doubts.. I am new to coding and stuff and need help .....thank you

Comment: For both queries, you've to execute `mc.fetchall()` so that you can have the rows returned by both queries. Store them into separate vars and then iterate over those variables.

Answer (score 0):

An empty plot can happen when your `x` and `y` have length 1. You can use `plt.plot([x],[y], '.')` to confirm. This would plot the data as points

Comment: no i am sorry it does not work. i need the x/y anyone axis to have the dates not those no.s.... thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: and I don't think the length of x and y is 1